Why does not dependencyManagement fix the Maven Enforcer convergence error?
I wonder why using the depependencyMangement section of Maven only seems to affect parts of my dependency tree, causing the enforcer plugin to fail. I originally got this error, that states that net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform is included as both version 5.6.0 and 5.13.0:
18:27:53,619 [ERROR] Dependency convergence error for net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.13.0 paths to dependency are:
18:27:53,619 [ERROR] +-no.acme-org.ze-domains.otherdep.adaptor:ze-domains-otherdep-adaptor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
18:27:53,619 [ERROR]   +-com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-jdbc-postgresql:jar:5.13.0:compile
18:27:53,619 [ERROR]     +-com.azure:azure-identity-extensions:jar:1.1.16:compile
18:27:53,619 [ERROR]       +-com.azure:azure-identity:jar:1.12.1:compile
18:27:53,619 [ERROR]         +-com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension:jar:1.3.0:compile
18:27:53,619 [ERROR]           +-net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.13.0:compile
18:27:53,619 [ERROR] and
18:27:53,619 [ERROR] +-no.acme-org.ze-domains.otherdep.adaptor:ze-domains-otherdep-adaptor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
18:27:53,619 [ERROR]   +-com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-jdbc-postgresql:jar:5.13.0:compile
18:27:53,619 [ERROR]     +-com.azure:azure-identity-extensions:jar:1.1.16:compile
18:27:53,619 [ERROR]       +-com.azure:azure-identity:jar:1.12.1:compile
18:27:53,620 [ERROR]         +-net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.6.0:compile

Setting the version using dependencyManagement to 5.14 only changes the error slightly slightly. If I add this
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
                <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
                <version>5.14.0</version>
            </dependency>

I only replace 5.6.0 in the error with 5.14.0:
18:28:32,688 [ERROR] Dependency convergence error for net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.13.0 paths to dependency are:
18:28:32,688 [ERROR] +-no.acme-org.ze-domains.otherdep.adaptor:ze-domains-otherdep-adaptor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]   +-com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-jdbc-postgresql:jar:5.13.0:compile
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]     +-com.azure:azure-identity-extensions:jar:1.1.16:compile
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]       +-com.azure:azure-identity:jar:1.12.1:compile
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]         +-com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension:jar:1.3.0:compile
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]           +-net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.13.0:compile
18:28:32,689 [ERROR] and
18:28:32,689 [ERROR] +-no.acme-org.ze-domains.otherdep.adaptor:ze-domains-otherdep-adaptor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]   +-com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-jdbc-postgresql:jar:5.13.0:compile
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]     +-com.azure:azure-identity-extensions:jar:1.1.16:compile
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]       +-com.azure:azure-identity:jar:1.12.1:compile
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]         +-net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.14.0:compile
18:28:32,689 [ERROR]           +-net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.14.0:compile

Why is 5.13 kept as a transitive dependency of com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension?

Full pom.xml
This is the actual pom.xml, just run through a "websafe" filter to replace company and project specific terms. This allows easy verification by just doing mvn install in whatever folder you stuff it. You will see some sections being commented out; that is the workaround for the issue I am having, but that still does not answer why Enforcer does not work, which would have made the workaround redundant.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>no.acme-org.ze-domains.otherdep.adaptor</groupId>
    <artifactId>ze-domains-otherdep-adaptor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ze-domains otherdep Adaptor: Web Application</name>

    <properties>
        <ze-domains-commons.version>116</ze-domains-commons.version>
        <jaxb-version>4.0.5</jaxb-version>
        <constretto.version>2.2.3</constretto.version>
        <resilience4j.version>2.2.0</resilience4j.version>
        <test-container.version>1.19.8</test-container.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>5.13.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                <version>1.26.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging-processor</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
                <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.constretto</groupId>
                <artifactId>constretto-core</artifactId>
                <version>${constretto.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.constretto</groupId>
                <artifactId>constretto-api</artifactId>
                <version>${constretto.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
                <version>3.44.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
                <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.16.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.17.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- ze-domains should not use joda-time (inherited from error-handling) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.7</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.acme-org</groupId>
                <artifactId>health-check</artifactId>
                <version>1.23</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.acme-org.errorhandling</groupId>
                <artifactId>errorhandling</artifactId>
                <version>54</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
                <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
                <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
                <version>5.14.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.15.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.acme-org</groupId>
                <artifactId>acme-org-products-spring6</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
                <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.10.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20240303</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Help for the Maven Enforcer Plugin: jna included in multiple versions -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jna</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>5.14.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.azure</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>azure-identity-extensions</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.1.16</version>-->
            <!--<exclusions>-->
                <!--<exclusion>-->
                    <!--<groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>jna</artifactId>-->
                <!--</exclusion>-->
            <!--</exclusions>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme-org</groupId>
            <artifactId>health-check</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot3</artifactId>
            <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vlkan.log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j2-logstash-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.constretto</groupId>
            <artifactId>constretto-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.constretto</groupId>
            <artifactId>constretto-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.constretto</groupId>
            <artifactId>constretto-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${constretto.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-blackbird</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>no.acme-org.ze-domains.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>ze-domains-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${ze-domains-commons.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme-org</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-cloud</artifactId>
            <version>58</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme-org.errorhandling</groupId>
            <artifactId>errorhandling</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>no.acme-org.log</groupId>
            <artifactId>acme-org-log-escalators</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>no.acme-org.ze-domains.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>ze-domains-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${ze-domains-commons.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${test-container.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.rnorth.visible-assertions</groupId>
                    <artifactId>visible-assertions</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${test-container.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.paranamer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.14</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.14</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opentest4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentest4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/operations</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/operations</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/operations</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*ExternalTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <dependencyConvergence />
                                <banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions />
                                <bannedDependencies>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>ch.qos.logback:logback-classic</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </bannedDependencies>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


The whole pom file would be helpful... ?

@khmarbaise Full pom.xml pasted in. My apologies if the original question did not have conclusive details: I thought I included everything relevant, but I realise not including the pom file would make interactive debugging much harder.

why do you have both the <dependencyManagement> part plus individual versions on some of the actual dependencies?

@cyberbrain sorry, but could you list a couple of these? I just went through 8 different dependencies without a single duplicated version in sight, so I am unsure if I should continue. The only such example is the jna one, but that is commented out (as per my comment above under the pom.xml header).

Oh I didn't mean duplicated versions, just asking about the mix of both variants. I personally find it harder to mix them so I usually stick to either the dependency-management or versions directly in the actual dependencies. It was really just a question :)

Good question! Since this is a single-module project, there is really not much to gain. This was added by other people before me, so I did not give it much thought. The only advantage to a depMan section is that you can declare versions for transitive dependencies, without including them. So if they are transitively not needed in the future, you do not get them needlessly.

Btw, I think I found the issue: the issue is with the jna dependency, but I only specified the jna-platform in the dM section  ...

the original problem you described (difference between 5.6.0 and 5.13.0) comes with jna-platform

The issue here is that I failed to realise the naming is off. It's not complaining about the same dependency!
The first error is about jna-platform. I then resolved that, but the next error is almost the same, but mentions jna - without the platform bit.
I only saw this when I grepped the output:
Step 1: no fixes
✦ ❯ mvn dependency:3.6.1:resolve | grep jna
22:29:00,313 [INFO]    net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.6.0:compile -- module com.sun.jna.platform [auto]
22:29:00,315 [INFO]    net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.13.0:compile -- module com.sun.jna [auto]

Step 2: added a version for jna-platform
✦ ❯ mvn dependency:3.6.1:resolve | grep jna
22:30:08,907 [INFO]    net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.14.0:compile -- module com.sun.jna.platform [auto]
22:30:08,909 [INFO]    net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.13.0:compile -- module com.sun.jna [auto]

Step 3 (missing above): added a version for jna
✦ ❯ mvn dependency:3.6.1:resolve | grep jna
22:30:41,594 [INFO]    net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.14.0:compile -- module com.sun.jna.platform [auto]
22:30:41,596 [INFO]    net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.14.0:compile -- module com.sun.jna [auto]

So in the end, the whole fix was just to add this patch (the + bits):
                 <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
                 <version>5.14.0</version>
             </dependency>
+            <dependency>
+                <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
+                <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
+                <version>5.14.0</version>
+            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                 <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>



You have another option for fixing: you could just specify the version of jna-platform to 5.13.0.
<properties>
    <jna.version>5.13.0</jna.version>
</properties>
:
:
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>${jna.version}</version>
</dependency>

I would recommend to use a property for the version number anyways, if you have just the jna-platform or also the jna version defined in your <dependencyManagement>, since on any future error by any newer version this should make it a bit easier to fix the dependencies.
You could also think of nailing down all the versions with [1.0.0] instead of 1.0.0 - of course the actual version numbers themself would have to be changed. This way maven would not dare to use any other version.

That's a good point. It does solve the issue. The "Why is 5.13 kept as a transitive dependency" question was thankfully just a silly reading bug on my behalf :)
